# How to use virtualenv + virtualenvwrapper properly with Vagrant?

Tags: virtualenv, vagrant, virtualenvwrapper

I found that the most convenient way of installing *virtualenv* + *virtualenvwrapper* is by using [virtualenvburrito](https://github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito).

Now I can manage to automate my pip installs in a vagrant provision by the following:

**Line in Vagrantfile:**

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "bootstrap.sh"
```

**Lines in bootstrap.sh:**

```
curl -s https://raw.github.com/brainsik/virtualenv-burrito/master/virtualenv-burrito.sh | $SHELL
source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh
cd /vagrant      
mkvirtualenv my_project
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Then I run `vagrant ssh` but then I have to run the following to access my virtual environment:

```
sudo -i
source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh
workon my_project
```

**I don't want to always have to run `sudo -i` and `source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh`, I just want to be able to run `workon my_project` directly**.

But

(I.) I can't seem to append `source /root/.venvburrito/startup.sh` to my `~/.profile` and

(II.) even if it was appended to that file I'd get a permissionerror. I can't seem to change the permissions for any protected file either.

Comment: Running into the same and looking for your take on a best practice. Wondering if you have thoughts on a final complete approach / solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to deal with (I.) and (II.) is to set the `privileged` attribute in the *Vagrantfile* to `false`.

See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/721813/vagrant-provision-script-echo-source-root-venvburrito-startup-sh-prof/721951#721951)